# SOAP Extensions

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, soap

Возникла необходимость написания клиента для стороннего Web-Service на C#. Всё бы ничего, если бы не необходимость корректировки Header-а отправляемого SOAP запроса. Покопавшись на MSDN понял что это можно реализовать при помощи SOAP Extension.

Осталось непонятным как же именно оживить эти самые расширения. 
Посоветуйте пожалуйста, где можно почерпнуть больше знаний по этой теме (если на русском языке - будет вообще замечательно). Если же есть практический опыт применения расширений - буду рад советам.